# How can I edit a json query

Tags: php, json

How do I get to affiliate_info1 Object? Can anyone help me ?

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => 1
        [httpStatus] => 200
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [page] => 1
                [current] => 1
                [count] => 1
                [pageCount] => 1
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [affiliate_info1] => riHPLAieOoKkeXMKKiNPiA
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [affiliate_info1] => XCuAQTtLkWTIKYMWKESlQS
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [affiliate_info1] => XCuAQTtLkWTIKYMWKESlQS
                                    )

                            )


                    )

                [dbSource] => branddb
            )

        [errors] => Array
            (
            )

        [errorMessage] => 
    )  

foreach($json as $item){

print_r($item->data);

}
```

Comment: What did you tried ? Where is your problem ?

Comment: Your subject and question are not related

Comment: I want to go to the
Dates:[affiliate_info1] => XCuAQTtLkWTIKYMWKESlQS
output

Comment: Use `$arr = json_decode($json, true)` when you decode your json so to get associative array, then you could do something like `echo $arr['data']['data'][0]['affiliate_info1']` you can loop through to get all the links

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($myObject->data->data as $row){
    echo $row->Stat-> affiliate_info1;
}
```

You simple loop around the `data` nested array and retrieve the values of your nested objects.

I guess you got confused when the object got nested arrays in it.